# How to remove integer values from column with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with info on multiple countries. The data is not very clean and some of the country names have integer values in them. like this `China2` or `Ukraine18`.

I want to remove the integer values from all entries in the `Country` column but am not able to find a robust way to do this. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Series.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
df['Country'] = df['Country'].str.replace('\d+', '')
```